# Closed SO question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

Today I've got a closed question ([Get file name using source map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834282)) with the reason: *We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.*

I've read SO policies once again and I'm still confused. From my point of view, it is a totally valid question and it doesn't violate any rules.

There are a lot of similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383865/how-to-use-sourcemaps-to-restore-the-original-file), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/how-to-use-javascript-source-maps-map-files) and others) about how the source-map works in Javascript. There is no way this question is different. It just about getting info from a js file based on source-map js file.

Could someone, more experienced, give me the right direction to work through the case?

**UPDATE**
I have updated my original question to make my intentions clearer for the community. I used @CodeCaster answer as the source of inspiration)

Comment: At best, the question you asked would be a duplicate of either of these other two, right? Unless you want a tool to do it for you... in which case the "seeking recommendations" closure would apply. Which would you say it is? The "easy way to do that" was interpreted as looking for a tool. And since you were already aware of these other questions that explained the sourcemap to source relationship, it doesn't seem a completely wrong interpretation. Maybe you can elaborate further.

Comment: @yivi Well, if we put it this way, then all the SO questions to a certain extent are duplicates))) In my case, of course, you are right, the questions are the same in terms of subject and scope, but they definitely different when we talk about the end goal and the way how to get there.

Comment: @yivi If we think this way then these two questions are also duplicates and we need to close one of them :-)

Comment: How are they different? Sorry, I'm having trouble seeing it. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the question could easily be interpreted as looking for external resources (a tool to do this easily), or as a duplicate if not. Could you elaborate further? Better if you do with edits to your question.

Comment: That there are other questions that (may) deserve closure is never a reason not to close other closure-deserving questions. There are many questions, and some slip through the cracks. Better focus on your question.

Comment: @yivi Ok, I'll try my best to paraphrase it. Thanks)

Comment: I think the main problem with your question is that you just refer to it as a 3rd party validator. If you were looking for instructions on how to use the tool you're using to get the output you want your question needs to include the name of the tool you're using and how. Or if you're asking if there's a way to just be able to tell which line numbers belong to which files without changing anything (which is how I read it), just clarify that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't see how that question is asking for off-site resources and have voted to reopen it, and it since had been.

Your question is really simple, paraphrased:

> webpack packs multiple files into one, and I want to obtain the original filename for a given line of code in the packed file from the source map.

The question contains the words "3rd party validator" and "tool", but other than that it has no relation whatsoever to asking for off-site resources, and those words aren't used to do so, and the question is on-topic.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not convinced by this reasoning. I certainly didn't stop reading there, I don't assume the actual voters did either. I asked for additional clarification to the OP, but they didn't provide any.

Comment: @yivi I don't support the mental gymnastics displayed by your first comment under this question. If a question asker doesn't think their question is a duplicate of other questions they've found (and it isn't), it must be a tool request? What? Let me turn it around for you: show me one phrase from said question that would indicate it is a request for an off-site resource.

Comment: I'm not doing any mental gymnastics, thank you. I would appreciate if you used a less confrontational tone.

Comment: I find the original question unclear at least, and I can understand others believing it's a request for a third-party tool. The fact that when pressed for clarification the OP simply went away does not give me a lot of confidence. So the options are dupe (at best, maybe, but I don't think so), unclear, or resource request. Certainly not something worth reopening in my opinion.

Comment: @yivi the question is very clear to me, and I have hardly any front-end experience: webpack packs multiple files into one, and they want to obtain the original filename for a given line of code in the packed file. This may be unclear, or a duplicate, but again, and I don't know how to ask this any more friendly: how on earth is that a resource request? Using that logic you can close any question as a resource request, because where is the documentation for that language/IDE/library? On another site.

Comment: @yivi resource requests are only resource requests when explicitly asking for a resource ("which tool can do ...", "where is a tutorial for ...", "what library can do ..."). Asking _how_ to do something is not a resource request. I find this rule pedantic as well, but it's what we'll have to do with.

Comment: The asker already knows about the relationship between the source and sourcemap. So what are they asking about? What's this "easy way to do it" they refer to? No, I don't think that by the same logic we could close all questions as resource requests. In this case, I think that interpreting as they are asking for a tool to accomplish the task is not a particularly big leap. And again, if it's not that, it's unclear. So why bother reopening at all?

Comment: @yivi it deserves reopening because what they are asking for is on-topic and clear. And yeah, weasel words. "The best way", "best practice" and "easy way" are not really helpful phrasings of questions, but not off-topic either.

Comment: I disagree, I think that the question as stated is not on-topic. But we are talking in circles anyway. I'll wait for the OP to provide additional details, if they ever do.

Comment: The question would definitly be on-topic if it would ask "How do I find the file from a sourcemap in IDE X", because that wouldn't ask for a list of possible tools that can do the job but how to do it in a specific tool. In the way it is stated now, I'm not so sure if on-topic/off-topic.

Comment: @BDL they are not asking for a tool and do not need a tool. A sourcemap is a one-to-one relation between a minified file and its original. The OP has **two different files** concatenated into one before minification, and they want to trace the minified sources back to the **original file** before concatenation. This is unrelated to any tool or IDE, and I still fail to see how all of this relates to a tool request.

Comment: It would really seem that some people here think that if a potential answer to a question is _"there's an app/tool/library for that"_, the question is an off-site resource request and therefore off-topic, and that frightens me.

Comment: Perhaps if you lead with that last comment your answer would be better received. Generally people react better to people admitting their fear than to brusque denunciations of others' behavior.

Comment: Guys, the ___2___ webpack ___output___ files are going through a ___3rd-party tool___ which returns ___1___ file. The question isn't about webpack, it's about whatever that 3rd party tool does. That makes it off-topic.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm at a loss for words, really. Asking about programming tools is on-topic, but this question isn't even about that code analysis tool; it is about source maps. What you claim in your comment also isn't the scenario here, the tool analyses the .js output file. But the question has been reopened, so this discussion is done anyway.

Comment: I've read over the question again, and I see he's not actually passing 2 files to the tool... Guess it's a duplicate then.

Comment: @Cerbrus so my point still stands, people read "3rd party" and "tool", and hurry for that "close" link.

Comment: Please don’t assume to know my intentions. That’s rather insulting.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you! You have expressed what I meant just in a few words. Indeed, I don't understand why the community decided the question is about the 3-rd party, I've read it multiple times and still don't see how it is about the 3-rd party. But, anyway, it is totally my bad, not others. I updated the original question and hope the people will understand my what I meant.